# Does QuickTime on Windows support HTTP Streaming?

Tags: video, streaming, iis, quicktime

Does QuickTime 7.6.9 (latest available on Windows) support HTTP Streaming?

I'm looking to add HTTP Streaming support for our IIS hosted application but looking at the examples from Microsoft's site, it seems to not be supported by QuickTime itself.  The examples work with Silverlight on the desktop and they work natively with iPhone, but I can't get it to work with QuickTime.

The example site is here:

http://www.iis.net/overview/IntegratedMediaPlatform

Silverlight link:

http://www.iis.net/media/experiencesmoothstreaming

iPhone video direct link:

http://mediadl.microsoft.com/mediadl/IISNET/SmoothMedia/iPhone/bbb/output/test.m3u8

iPhone container:

http://www.iis.net/iPhone

the iPhone container web page works on my iPhone.  This page didn't work on any desktop browser (Chrome or Safari, I wouldn't expect it to work anywhere else).  Safari shows the splash image but video doesn't start to play.

Loading the iPhone direct video link in QuickTime doesn't show any video or plays.  I can download the .m3u8 file and save it locally, so it does download fine.  I also tried VLC without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question.  HTTP Streaming is a feature of QuickTime X only and only works on OSX.  Even on OSX, it's only supported in the standalone QuickTime X player or in Safari, but not in QuickTime embedded in Firefox or Chrome).